# JSTL doesn't seem to work with Eclipse Juno

Tags: jsp, jstl, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I'm learning JSP and trying to use JSTL with it.
Am using Eclipse Juno, and followed the installation instruction from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

but when trying to run it, it gives error message:
message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

and
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Have dropped javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.2.jar and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar in project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/  folder and refreshed the folder, and just to make sure I've also right clicked on them and clicked Build Path -> Configure Build Path and made sure they are both under the Web App Libraries.

Have tried different version of JSTL, ie 1.2.1 and 1.2, all of them gives the same error. and also deleted the .jar files and still giving the same error, so am assuming the files somehow aren't being read or the set up isn't right.

Have tried to search for solution but don't seem to find others with the same issue... (either no one had the same issue or just don't know where to look.)

The simple .jsp code I'm trying to run is below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
<c:import url="hotels.html" var="sf"/>
<x:parse doc="${sf}" varDom="dom"/>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsing hotels.html</title>
</head>
<body>
    <x:out select="$tag/img/@alt"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please help...
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're using right JSP/Servlet version in web.xml. Also, try to clean your project, rebuild it and redeploy it in your tomcat installation.

Comment: Am using web.xml version 3.0 with JSTL version 1.2.1                     Have cleaned and rebuilt the project, and try to run it again on the server but the same error message came up... Have tried to use web.xml version 2.5 with JSTL version 1.2.1, still doesn't work.    Below is the version code in web.xml                              <web-app version="3.0"                      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

Comment: Have also tried to use web.xml version 2.5 with JSTL version 1.2, (still the same error message, have rebuilt the project as well) The web.xml version code is: <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

Comment: That's your server telling you it can't find the taglibs.  Is there actually a .tld file matching the URIs you referenced in those .jar files?